# JavaScript (JQuery) change name of parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the name of a parameter in a JavaScript object?

My question arises from that the JQuery AutoComplete is very fussy about parameter names and requires a parameter name either label or value.

My data object.

```
data....
data.receivers[].id
data.receivers[].name
data....
```

What I would like to do is make an alias/reference or similar conceptual like this.

```
data.receivers[].label = data.receivers[].name
```

So I would like to change a parameter from name to label. I have done it this way but I don't like to duplicate the data which I believe .map does.

```
var callBack = function(data) {
    var autoCompleteData = jQuery.map(data.receivers, function(receiver, i){
          return {label: receiver.name, id: receiver.id };
    });

    $("input#reciever").autocomplete({
        source: autoCompleteData,
        focus: function(event, receiver) {
            $("input#reciever").val(receiver.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, receiver) {
            $("input#reciever").val(receiver.item.label); 
            $("input#recieverId").val(receiver.item.id);
            return false;
        }

    });
}
```

Ps. I could change the JSON return data from my server but I want to keep the names logical and intuitive and not be forced to model by data object according to JQuery's constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update your object collection in-place, you can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of `$.map()`:

```
$.each(data.receivers, function() {
    this.label = this.name;
    delete this.name;    
});

$("input#reciever").autocomplete({   // suggest $("#receiver") instead
     source: data.receivers,
     // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was a good answers. I will have to think about this. The thing with your code is that create a new property and sets it thru a loop. What I was wondering was also conceptual in JavaScript what is possible and what isn't. e.g If One can make name changes to properties. Like changing a reference/pointer name, without any computation.

Comment: To my knowledge, that's the only way to do it: you cannot remap properties without creating new ones and removing the originals.